# How do I update Windows Environment Variables to use pipx

Tags: windows, environment-variables, pipx

I've installed pipx using command:
`python -m pip install --user pipx` (instructions: https://pypi.org/project/pipx/)

When I try to run it, I get the error:
`'pipx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

The `pipx.exe` installed on my machine in this location:
`c:\users\my admin user\appdata\roaming\python\python311\Scripts\pipx.exe`

If I navigate to the above parent "Scripts" folder, I can run the command `pipx --version` successfully. If I'm not in this folder, then the command fails with the above error.

I've tried adding `c:\users\my admin user\appdata\roaming\python\python311` to my `Path` `System Variables`

[image]

[image]

But I still get the error. I'm not 100% clear on how Environment Variables work in Windows. I think things may be complicated in the due to my company security policies, I am working in a non-admin Windows profile (eg "`my standard user`") and running my command prompt as an admin user ("`my admin user`")